# How to give multiple system variables at environment variables the same priority?

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables

I have a list of system variables some of those are these 3:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common files\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

i need to have C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin
on top to make my .bat file work. It has this line:

```
start java -jar "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Gameserver\builds\LoginServer1.jar"
```

But the i can't use eclipse anymore, i get an classnot found exception when trying to start eclipse?
Is there a way to make it both work? I'm really wondering why everything has to be so illogical, chaotic and extremely complex

Comment: About setting the jvm for Eclipse look into the [eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini). As you understand how computer and operating systems work, you will realize that it is complex, but logical and organized. ;-)

Comment: not working for me. I added to the ini file: -vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: You need a newline after `-vm` and it must be before the entry for `-vmargs`. That way it works for me. From your question I understand, that you **don't** want to use jdk11 for eclipse.

Comment: I did that like you said. Not working either. So you say i should not use jdk11?

Comment: Well, if it doesn't work with jdk11, I would try a older version. Maybe you should extend your question and add details on the ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: i just de-installed jdk11 and reinstalled jdk8 and all problems are gone. They recommend using jdk11, i expect it to work. Now the question i started seems to have no connection with the solution....

Comment: Great. I'm also still on jdk8.

Comment: Java 11 works fine with the current release of Eclipse (2018-12)